# Background processes in Elixir

Tags: elixir, background-process, phoenix-framework

I have a website where I'll have to create multiple background processes. 
Each process will be alive at most 20-30 minutes and it won't do any computations, instead it'll merely check a state of some application  once in a minute passing to it a certain list of arguments. That's it. Supposedly per hour I'll create 5 such tasks.

These process don't have to communicate with each other.

How is it better to organize all that in Elixir? Via Task? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Via monitored `Task`, or via `GenServer`, it’s hard to tell basing on this description. I have voted to close the question as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a simple scheduler like this you can for instance use `Process.send_after` combined with GenServer's `handle_info`, because message sent from the function above is handle as an info.

Eg.

```
defmodule YourGenServer do
  use GenServer

  def init(initial_value) do
    Process.send_after(self, :check_state, 1000 * 60 * 20) # 20 minutes delay
  end

  def handle_info(:check_state, state) do
    # do the task
    Process.send_after(self, :check_state, 1000 * 60 * 20)
  end
end
```

What's better solution for that? Tasks and Agents are GenServers as well, just their API is simpler. I used in my example GenServer to show you how it can look like. Propably the best idea for you is to use wrapper, that encapsulates server's callbacks under the hood and if you want to change the engine, you just do it smoothly.

Comment: I understand this example is contrived, but it lacks the main most complicated part: how supervising is done (if any.) I would produce an `Agent`, that _holds and supervises_ it’s nested tasks.

Comment: It depends how this check of the application'state is important- if it's crucial I would use dedicated worker for the supervisor and re-create new process each time previous one failed. I guess it's just a check, so even if 3 of 5 tasks would work, it would be fine.